# extraer datos de un array e insertarlos en otro array en vue

Tags: array, vue.js

Amigos tengo lo siguiente

```
this.array1 = [{respuesta1, respuesta2}];
this.array2 = [{id: 1, pregunta: 'pregunta1'}, {id: 2, pregunta: 'pregunta2'}]
```

lo que necesito saber es como puedo insertar en mi `this.array2` otra propiedad llamada `respuesta` y que se vea de la siguiente forma

```
this.array2 = [{id: 1, pregunta: 'pregunta1', respuesta: 'respuesta1'}, {id: 2, pregunta: 'pregunta2', respuesta: 'respuesta2'}]
```

Estoy trabajando con vue.js

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.array2[index]['respuesta'] = 'respuesta2'`, donde `index` viene a ser la posición donde ubicarás la nueva propiedad respuesta.